# Почему неправильно работает проверка на уникальность?

Tags: php, yii2

Пишу код приложения на yii2-advanced, хочу сделать проверку на уникальность.

В коде модели пишу **`['name', 'unique']`**, и вроде все работает, да не так как надо.

При попытке создать запись с именем, которое уже существует, вместо отображения подписи **"Имя занято"** перебрасывает на страницу ошибки **"Отсутствуют параметры: id"**.

Как исправить?

Не думаю, что это поможет, но...

Код экшена контроллера:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if(!$model->saveCategory()){
            $model->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Код методов  модели:

```
public function saveCategory()
{
    $this->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
    if ($this->image){
        $image = $this->image;
        $this->image = "/uploads/categories/$this->name".".".$this->image->extension;
        if ($this->save()){
            $this->upload($image);
        }
    }
    // else $this->save();
    else return false;
}

public function upload($image)
{
    if($this->validate()){
        $image->saveAs("uploads/categories/{$this->name}.{$image->extension}");
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Код представления:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Categories */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="categories-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::button('Назад', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'onclick' => 'history.back();']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Код представления:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Categories */

$this->title = 'Update Categories: ' . $model->name;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Categories', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->name, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Update';
?>
<div class="categories-update">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть код контроллера кинули, что ли

Comment: @Андрей Добровольский, добавил

Comment: И код представления с формой, пожалуйста

Comment: @Андрей Добровольский, добавил

Comment: Попробуйте if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно привести код к такому виду :

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
$model = $this->findModel($id);
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    if(!$model->saveCategory()){
        if($model->save()){
           return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
       }
    }

}
return $this->render('update', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

}

Вот тут вы ничего не проверяете, сохранили или нет - вы в любом случае делаете редирект с id модели, которая возможно даже не создана.
В этом месте нужно проверки.

```
 if(!$model->saveCategory()){
    $model->save();
}
```